# Angular 4 use typescript parse response data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the response data like as:

```
{
  "content": [{
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "v7001",
    "status": 1,
    "userInfo": {
      "id": 1,
      "fullName": "Naruto Uzumaki",
      "firstName": "Naruto",
      "lastName": "Uzumaki",
      "address": "Konoha",
      "dob": 1509901200000
    }
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "v7002",
    "status": 0,
    "userInfo": {
      "id": 2,
      "fullName": "Hinata Hyuga",
      "firstName": "Hinata",
      "lastName": "Hyuga",
      "address": "Konoha",
      "dob": 1509987600000
    }
  }],
  "last": true,
  "totalElements": 3,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "size": 20,
  "number": 0,
  "first": true,
  "sort": null,
  "numberOfElements": 3
}
```

and user Angular 4 to display data. I create 2 interface: User-info

```
export class UserInfo {
  id: number;
  fullName: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  address: string;
  dob: string
}
```

and user

```
import {UserInfo} from './user-info'

export class User {
  id: number;
  userName: String;
  status: String;
  userInfo: UserInfo;
}
```

user service :

```
getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.userUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().data as User[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I check on network tab, the API gets successfully data.
on component:

```
user: User[];
selectedUser: User;
newUser: User;
data: any={};

constructor(private router: Router,
            private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getUsers().then(user => this.user = user); 
}
```

and in html:

```
 <tr role="row" class="odd" *ngFor="let lst of user.content">
   <td>{{lst.userInfo.fullName}}</td>
   <td>{{lst.userInfo.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

but when the app run,the error message display on console: content invalid.
this.user is undefined. please advice me.

Comment: `user` is an array in your component, it does not have `content` property

Comment: Side note: [http](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) has been deprecated by the angular team. Use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting to receive `users` collection from `getUsers` method then do return `response.json().content` inspite of `response.json().data`, and then `User[]` make sense to provide tooling for collection to be `User[]`

```
getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.userUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().content as User[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Consumption**

```
this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.users = users);
```

**HTML**

```
<tr role="row" class="odd" *ngFor="let lst of users">
  <td>{{lst.userInfo.fullName}}</td>
  <td>{{lst.userInfo.address}}</td>
</tr>
```